# Is there some method or process to create scripts for all user tables from a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to replicate a database on one of our servers on my localhost. It has around 90 user tables, and I do not fancy hitting each one and getting a create script for it so I can create the tables on my localhost.

Is there some kind of command or process which would generate the create script for all these tables?  Keep in mind that I don't have `sa` authority on the server I am trying to replicate.  Way back when it was possible to do this in SQL Server Management Studio by highlighting all the objects and selecting script for all of them at once. In SSMS 2012 however, this cannot be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the database name, and choose tasks-> 'generate scripts' in SSMS.

Comment: Holy moly!  That was easy!  Wow, you have just save me a couple of hours of work.  I probably should have found this on my own, but I wasn't being creative enough, I guess.  Thanks!